# Devextreme - How to make Popup Editing in a dxDataGrid render when load the page without open the Popup screen?

Tags: jquery, devextreme

I really want to get an instance of a dxDataGrid within my Popup Editing to update my Datasource for that dxDataGrid but I can't do it because if I try to get an instance of it, it returns undefined.

I tried using deferRendering for Popup Editing but the result is still the same.

[image: devextreme popup]